# Knockout cleanNode() removes jquery event bindings?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Knockout's `cleanNode()` function seems to be removing jQuery's event bindings on elements inside the node. How can I prevent this?
There is not much documentation I could find on `cleanNode()` either.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to keep the jQuery bindings code separate from the knockout bindings. In this way, you can simply call the function to redo the jQuery bindings.
Unfortunately, a code refactor of existing code might be required to do this.

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer. It's basically just saying "do it differently from the beginning"

Answer (score 6):

Directly from the [knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html):

***"Overriding the clean-up of external data***

*When removing an element, Knockout runs logic to clean up any data associated with the element. As part of this logic, Knockout calls jQuery’s cleanData method if jQuery is loaded in your page. In advanced scenarios, you may want to prevent or customize how this data is removed in your application. Knockout exposes a function, ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.cleanExternalData(node), that can be overridden to support custom logic. For example, to prevent cleanData from being called, an empty function could be used to replace the standard cleanExternalData implementation:"*

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.cleanExternalData = function () {
    // Do nothing. Now any jQuery data associated with elements will
    // not be cleaned up when the elements are removed from the DOM.
};
```

Lately i went crazy because of endless debug sessions.

I saw this question, and I hope my answer gives a more immediate solution for those who are still searching.

Comment: This method is working fine, so i wrote a short function that override the cleanExternalData method, call clearNode and set original method back.  `private koClearNode(element: HTMLElement)
        {
            var original = ko.utils.domNodeDisposal['cleanExternalData'];
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal['cleanExternalData'] = function () { };
            ko.cleanNode(element);
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal['cleanExternalData'] = original;
        }`

Also works in TypeScript, where cleanExternalData is not in typings.

Comment: @prespic good solution, but I suggest you to write you own answer, to make it more visible to future users

Answer (score 5):

**@T-moty** answer is working fine, so i wrote a short function that override the cleanExternalData method, call clearNode and set original method back.

```
    private koClearNode(element: HTMLElement)
    {
        var original = ko.utils.domNodeDisposal['cleanExternalData'];
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal['cleanExternalData'] = function () { };
        ko.cleanNode(element);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal['cleanExternalData'] = original;
    }
```

Also works in TypeScript, where cleanExternalData is not in typings.

Comment: This is a good solution and is working. This or the one its based on should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

cleanNode does not take any parameters that would allow you to prevent this behavior.  I think your best option would be to create your own method based off of the Knockout function but without the jQuery cleaning.  Without having built a sample app to verify, I would look creating a function that is identical to cleanSingleNode(node) and remove this line:

```
if ((typeof jQuery == "function") && (typeof jQuery['cleanData'] == "function"))
        jQuery['cleanData']([node]);
```

You can check the debug source here to get more info on other related internal functions: http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js