# knockout applyBindings changed event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to listen for `applyBindings` event in ko?

I have searched google and SO and can't find a way. The answer needs to be supported ie not calling internal functions that may get changed in the future by the KO developer(s).

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894091/knockout-how-to-check-whether-bindings-have-been-applied-to-page-area) is *not* similar as it asks how to check if applyBindings *has been called*. I want to know *when* it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, it's pretty easy to intercept any method call because you can just modify the object. Thus you can replace `ko.applyBindings` with your own function that does whatever you want (before or after you call the original):

```
ko.applyBindings = (function(original) {
    return function () {
        original.apply(this, arguments);
        alert('ko.applyBindings called');
    };
})(ko.applyBindings);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/4a2vK/

NOTE: This method will behave differently between the debug and release versions of Knockout. Knockout uses `ko.applyBindings` internally for the `template` binding, and when using the release version, it will always call the internal `ko.applyBindings` function, whereas in the debug version, it will call our replacement function.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know you could do this, admittedly I'm not so great with javascript.