# Should I use some Javascript MVVM framework or use old style way of building app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mvvm, knockout.js

I know `Knockout.JS` and `Angular.JS` at the intermediate's level. It is great for building Single Page applications. However, my new project is going to be very large and would last almost 3 years building it (approximately 50 pages). I am pretty sure Single Page application concept is not going to fit here due to the complexity of the project and large number of pages that have varied functionality.

My question: How would these frameworks help me in building large scale application? Should I bind Controllers/ViewModel on per page basis? Also, should I consider combining all the scripts or should I load them on per page basis? Basically I am not sure how to architect my application.

Comment: who said that KnockoutJS or AngularJS fit only in SPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Knockout.js for multi page applications
There are several options for handling this type of thing that are detailed here: [Example of knockoutjs pattern for multi-view applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676988/example-of-knockoutjs-pattern-for-multi-view-applications/8680668#8680668)