# Dynamically composing a UI using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm working with the awesome Knockout.js library on a project and am looking for a way to compose sections of my UI at run-time.

For example I have have a couple of templates (simplified, below) that are made up of child templates.  Id like to pass a view model to these and render them, and then be able to append (and remove) the contents from criteria form.

```
<!-- used with LineGraphModel -->
<script type="text/html" name="linegraph-template">
  <div id="LineGraph">
      <div data-bind="contextTemplate: { name: 'series-template', data: seriesChoices, context: { selected: series } }"></div>
      <div data-bind="contextTemplate: { name: 'xaxis-template', data: xAxisChoices, context: { selected: xaxis } }"></div>
      <div data-bind="contextTemplate: { name: 'daterange-template', data: dateRangeChoices, context: { selected: dateRange } }"></div>
      <div data-bind="template: { name: 'button-template', data: $data }"></div>
  </div>
</script>

<!-- used with PieChartModel -->
<script type="text/html" name="piechart-template">
  <div id="PieGraph">
    <div data-bind="contextTemplate: { name: 'series-template', data: seriesChoices, context: { selected: series } }"></div>
    <div data-bind="contextTemplate: { name: 'daterange-template', data: dateRangeChoices, context: { selected: dateRange } }"></div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'button-template', data: $data }"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

I've begin wandering down the path of `ko.renderTemplate` but I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to create a new div and append the result to an existing div.  Is this possible, or is there another approach I should be trying?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think some of the info here is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676988/example-of-knockoutjs-pattern-for-multi-view-applications/8680668#8680668.  Basically, you could use `ko.applyBindings` against individual DOM elements with your individual view models or create an "app" level view model that contains your child view models and use the `template` binding against them.

Comment: I am doing exactly that in an app I am currently working on - Viewmodels that can have arbitrary "child viewmodels", and a binding that allows me to say "render this template with that child viewmodel".  I want to package it as a library on Github, but haven't gotten to it yet. Let me know if you are interested - I can put together something quickly.

Comment: @janfoeh -- I'd love to see your approach.  Based on Ryan's feedback, I've muddled through to a workable solution, but I'm not very happy with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After writing all this down, it dawns on me that this might exceed the scope of your question quite a bit. If that is indeed the case, I apologize; I hope that you still might get some value out of it.

This stuff here comes from a real app I have been working on for several months now. It's a quick and dirty extraction and might contain bugs or typos where I removed app-specific code or simplified it to make it easier to follow.

With it, I can

- arbitrarily nest viewmodels
- dynamically add viewmodels on the fly
- render Knockout templates bound to these nested viewmodels, and use the results flexibly

Here's a quick overview how it works.

Pretend for a second you are going to build an app that shows a list of messages. The user can click on a message to open a modal dialog and reply. We have three viewmodels:

1. a root viewmodel called `Main`
2. a `MessageList` that takes care of displaying the list of messages
3. a third one called `MessageReply` that is responsible for the reply functionality.

All our viewmodel constructors are neatly namespaced in `app.viewmodels`. Let's set them up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mainVm,
      messageListVm,
      messageReplyVm;

  // we start with Main as the root viewmodel
  mainVm = new app.viewmodels.Main();

  // MessageList is a child of Main
  messageListVm = mainVm.addChildVm('MessageList');

  // and MessageReply in turn is a child of MessageList
  messageReplyVm = messageListVm.addChildVm('MessageReply');

  // the root is the only one that gets bound directly
  ko.applyBindings(mainVm);
});
```

Our markup looks something like this:

```html
<body>
  <!-- context here: the Main viewmodel -->

  <div data-bind="childVm: 'MessageList'">
    <!-- context here: the MessageList viewmodel -->

    <ul data-bind="foreach: messages">
      <!-- context here: the individual message object -->
      <li>
        <p data-bind="text: body, modal: {viewmodelName: 'MessageReply', parentViewmodel: $parent, setupViewmodelWith: $data, templateName: 'message-reply-template'}">

        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<script id="message-reply-template" type="text/html">
  <!-- context here: the MessageReply viewmodel -->
  <div>
    <textarea data-bind="value: message().body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" data-bind="click: submit">
  </div>  
</script>
```

There are two custom bindings in there, `childVm` and `modal`. The former just looks up a child viewmodel ands sets it as the binding context, whereas the `modal` binding is responsible for rendering the template in the correct context and handing the result to a separate JS library.

Viewmodels gain the ability to nest by borrowing constructor functions, a `Parent`, a `Child` or both at the same time. [Here is the source for them](https://gist.github.com/janfoeh/7914187#file-viewmodel-base-js).

**Parents**

If a viewmodel should be able to have child viewmodels, it borrows the `Parent` constructor:

```
app.viewmodels.Main = function Main() {
  app.viewmodels.Parent.apply(this);

  this.currentUser = //.. imagine the current user being loaded here from somewhere
};
```

As a parent viewmodel, `Main` has gained three things:

1. `.addChildVm(string)`: add a child viewmodel by passing its name. It's automatically looked up in the `app.viewmodel` namespace.
2. `.getVm(name)`: returns the child viewmodel named 'name'
3. `._childVms`: an observable list containing all the children

**Children**

Every viewmodel apart from the root `Main` is at least a child viewmodel. `MessageList` is both a child to `Main`, and a parent to `MessageReply`. Very appropriately to its name, it houses the messages to be displayed in the list.

```
app.viewmodels.MessageList = function MessageList() {
  app.viewmodels.Parent.apply(this);
  app.viewmodels.Child.apply(this);

  // children need to set this, so we can find them by name through .getVm()
  this._viewmodelName = function() { return "MessageList"; };

  this.currentUser = null;

  this.messages = ko.observableArray([]);

  this.init = function init() {
    that.currentUser = that._parentVm.currentUser;

    var messages = GetMessages() // pseudocode - load our messages from somewhere
    this.messages( messages);
  };
};
```

As a child viewmodel, `MessageList` gains:

- the ability to access its parent through `this._parentVm`
- an optional `init` function, which is called automatically by the parent if present

So above when we added `MessageList` to `Main` with

```
messageListVm = mainVm.addChildVm('MessageList');
```

, `Main`

- created a new instance of `MessageList`
- added the instance to its own children
- and called the childs `init`

The child then set itself up by getting a reference to the current user, which is mainted by the parent `Main` viewmodel.

**Our last viewmodel: the `MessageReply`**

`MessageReply` is just a child viewmodel; like it's parent `MessageList` did itself, it too copies the current user when initialized. It expects to be handed a Message object from the modal binding, then creates a new Message in reply to it. That reply can be edited and submitted through the form in the modal.

```
app.viewmodels.MessageReply = function MessageReply() {
  app.viewmodels.Child.apply(this);

  this._viewmodelName = function() { return "MessageReply"; };

  var that = this;

  this.currentUser = null;

  // called automatically by the parent MessageList
  this.init = function init() {
    that.currentUser = that._parentVm.currentUser;
  };

  this.messageWeAreReplyingTo = ko.observable();

  // our reply
  this.message = ko.observable();

  // called by the 'modal' binding
  this.setup = function setup(messageWeAreReplyingTo) {

    // the modal binding gives us the message the user clicked on
    this.messageWeAreReplyingTo( messageWeAreReplyingTo );

    // imagine that Message is a model object defined somewhere else
    var ourReply = new Message({
      sender: that.currentUser,
      recipient: that.messageWeAreReplyingTo().sender();
    });

    this.message( ourReply );
  };

  // this is triggered by the form submit button in the overlay
  this.submit = function submit() {
    // send the message to the server
  }
};
```

**The 'childVm' binding**

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/janfoeh/7914187#file-binding-childvm-js)

```html
<body>
  <!-- context here: the Main viewmodel -->

  <div data-bind="childVm: 'MessageList'">
    <!-- context here: the MessageList viewmodel -->
  </div>
```

This is merely a convenience wrapper around Knockouts own 'with:' binding. It takes a viewmodel name as its value accessor, looks up a child viewmodel of that name in the current binding context, and uses the 'with:' binding to set that child as the new context.

**The 'waitForVm' binding**

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/janfoeh/7914187#file-binding-waitforvm-js)

This isn't used in the example above, but is quite useful if you want to add viewmodels dynamically at runtime, as opposed to before `ko.applyBindings`. This way, you can delay initializing parts of your application until the user actually wants to interact with them.

`waitForVm` waits until the specified viewmodel is available before binding its child elements. It does not modify the binding context.

```html
<div data-bind="waitForVm: 'MessageList'">
  <!-- bindings in here are not executed until 'MessageList' is loaded -->
  <div data-bind="childVm: 'MessageList'"> ... </div>
</div>
```

**The 'modal' binding**

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/janfoeh/7914187#file-binding-modal-js)

This takes a Knockout template, marries it to a viewmodel, renders it and passes the result to an external JS library that handles the modal dialog.

Imagine that this modal library

1. when initialized, creates a DOM container before `</body>`
2. when asked to display the modal, takes this container and shows it overlayed over the rest of the page, lightbox-style

Let's look at the modal binding in action again:

```html
      <!-- context here: the individual message object -->
      <li>
        <p data-bind="text: body, modal: {viewmodelName: 'MessageReply', parentViewmodel: $parent, setupViewmodelWith: $data, templateName: 'message-reply-template'}">

        </p>
      </li>
```

`modal` will

- use the parent viewmodel `MessageList`, found in our current binding context at `$parent`
- ask it via `getVm()` for its child viewmodel instance `MessageReply`
- add a click binding to the `<p>`, which when activated

  - calls `setup()` on `MessageReply`, handing it our `$data` - the current message the user clicked on
  - prepares the modal and
  - renders the template 'message-reply-template', bound to the `MessageReply` viewmodel, into the modals DOM container

Comment: Such a great answer with so much detail.  I've learned so much from this over the last hour or so.  Thanks!!