# Add new properties to Knockout viewmodel after ko.applyBindings is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, webforms

In a (webforms) page I have a button that opens a [jqueryui dialogue](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) which is loaded dynamically.
The problem is that I want this dialogue to be master of its own knockout view model but the view model is already set in the main page.

I suppose it is *not* possible to add new properties to the view model after `ko.applyBindings` is called.
Instead I should be looking into another design. But which?

- Applying [bindings to different parts of the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7342861/521554) would require me to some big redesigns I hope to avoid right now.
- Having all the dialoge bindings as a list of key-values is possible but not very elegant IMHO. The main page would then only have to add a `vm.dialogueKeyvalueCollection`.
- My present, possible, solution is to have the main form add the dialogue's properties `vm.dialogue.userName() vm.dialogue.searchResult()` but then my html controls [won't bind as they are created *after* `applyBindings` is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067276/521554). The present solution for this is to call `ApplyBindings` again like so: `ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#dialog-form')[0]);` for the added HTML. I was in the belief (and still somewhat am) that to call `applyBindings` for different DOM elements one must not be nested inside another. Binding to dynamic HTML is commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826482/get-dynamically-inserted-html-to-work-with-knockoutjs) and jsfiddled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FCN5p/).
- ?

Comment: I have noticed, through trial and horror, that it is ok to call `applyBindings(vm, domElement)` on a newly created part of the DOM. My guess is that once a control has been bound it cannot be again; while new DOM elements have never been bound so binding them is ok. I guess, as I have not tried, that the new elements/DOM tree must be placed at an existing leaf since traversing this new DOM must not traverse into already bound elements. _Was this at all understandable?_

Answer (score 2):

I do a lot of composition with nested view models, often for the purpose of creating dialogues modals. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528779/100342) for a full-fledged answer.

It might be simpler to try and get away with just using the `with` binding, though. You could create a `dialogueViewmodel` observable property on your viewmodel.

Just fill it with one or more observable keys when you're ready to show the dialogue, such as

```
this.dialogueViewmodel({
  markup: ko.observable("<h1>Kittens!</h1>")
});
```

and wrap it in a `with` binding:

```
<!-- ko with: dialogueViewmodel -->
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" data-bind="html: markup">
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

As long as `dialogueViewmodel` is `null`, nothing gets bound and rendered. This only happens when you add your dialogue data - no need to fiddle with `applyBindings` again.

You will probably have to write your own binding to interface with jQueryUI.dialogue, though.

Third option: I have written a [modal library](https://github.com/janfoeh/veiljs) that comes with a Knockout binding out of the box. Here's a [JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/11Lkbs82/). If you're not set on jQueryUI, that might be an alternative; while the documentation is not perfect, I'd be happy to help you any way I can and fix the docs along the way.

Comment: I didn't know what `width` did, had only seen it in text but not looked into it. Looks promising. Might be the Answer I was looking for but not until I have tested it myself. At the time of writing I (unfortunately) have decided on a more crude solution. I will hopefully remember to keep this post updated as I continue and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Can you `ko.applyBindingsToNode` function to bind the appended html.

`ko.applyBindingsToNode(appendedelement,{ binding options})`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is applyBindingsToNode from [Sharpkit](http://sharpkit.net/help/SharpKit.KnockoutJs/SharpKit.KnockoutJs/Knockout/applyBindingsToNode(HtmlElement,JsObject,Object,JsString).htm)?